# How can i save the desired data on EditText by using onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, android-sdk-tools, activity-lifecycle

I am trying to design an Android application, in that application i have sent the data from First Activity to Second Activity. In the Second Activity I am using this code

```js
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

to save the data when application moves to landscape to portrait mode but in my application even i am using both of these but the data is not being saved. On rotation the data is getting destroyed which application is having in `EditText` View.

Please Check the below code, give the suggestions where i am doing the mistake to save the data
**MainActivity.java**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name,age;
    TextView text_name,text_age;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        text_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_edit);
        text_age=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_age);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.click);

        //Button Click to send data to another activity

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                String user_name=name.getText().toString();
                String user_age=age.getText().toString();
                bundle.putString("UName",user_name);
                bundle.putString("UAge",user_age);
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondClass.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    
}
```

**SecondClass.java**

```js
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
    EditText name,age;
    TextView text_name,text_age;
    String namer,ager;
    private String savedName,savedAge;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity_layout);
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        text_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_edit);
        text_age=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_age);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            savedInstanceState.get(savedName);
            name.setText(savedName);
            savedInstanceState.get(savedAge);
            age.setText(savedAge);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            Intent i=getIntent();
            Bundle bundle=i.getExtras();
            namer=bundle.getString("UName");
            name.setText(namer);
            ager=bundle.getString("UAge");
            age.setText(ager);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(savedName,namer);
        outState.putString(savedAge,ager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            savedInstanceState.get(savedName);
            name.setText(savedName);
            savedInstanceState.get(savedAge);
            age.setText(savedAge);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            Intent i=getIntent();
            Bundle bundle=i.getExtras();
            namer=bundle.getString("UName");
            name.setText(namer);
            ager=bundle.getString("UAge");
            age.setText(ager);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: try moving `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` after  this statement `outState.putString(savedAge,ager);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put and get value in saved instance with a key, and first put your data in 
'outState' then call '

> super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

try this:

```js
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
    private static final String SAVED_NAME="savedName";
    private static final String SAVED_AGE="savedAge";
    EditText name,age;
    TextView text_name,text_age;
    String namer,ager;
    private String savedName,savedAge;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity_layout);
        name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        text_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_edit);
        text_age=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_age);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            namer  = savedInstanceState.get(SAVED_NAME);
            name.setText(namer);
            ager = savedInstanceState.get(SAVED_AGE);
            age.setText(ager);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            Intent i=getIntent();
            Bundle bundle=i.getExtras();
            namer=bundle.getString("UName");
            name.setText(namer);
            ager=bundle.getString("UAge");
            age.setText(ager);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(savedName,namer);
        outState.putString(savedAge,ager);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            namer  = savedInstanceState.get(SAVED_NAME);
            name.setText(namer);
            ager = savedInstanceState.get(SAVED_AGE);
            age.setText(ager);
        }
        if (savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            Intent i=getIntent();
            Bundle bundle=i.getExtras();
            namer=bundle.getString("UName");
            name.setText(namer);
            ager=bundle.getString("UAge");
            age.setText(ager);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Hamideza , Thanks for giving the answer